# What gives researchers a reason to test the Radiation Resistance of organisms?

Tags: microbiology, radiation, research-process

I was reading about the [Thermococcus Gammatolerans](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thermococcus_gammatolerans) and its absurdly high radiation resistance, when something occurred to me.

**What reason did anyone have in the first place to subject this thing to this level of radiation?**

I'm very curious to find out about the process behind deciding which organisms to test the radiation resistance of. Is there an ongoing effort to test the resistance of every species yet discovered? Or are there other factors in determining which species should be subjected to this kind of testing?

Comment: OK. You cite the Wikipedia page on this organism. There is a reference to a paper about it on that page. I suggest you look at that paper (no need to read it all) and find out where this organism is found. That should give you an indication of why they chose it. Why should anyone be interested in (or fund research in) the resistance of living organisms to radiation? This is not Guiness book of records stuff — animal with the longest penis and the like — they are interested in the molecular mechanism. Ask yourself what use that might be. Learn to save your own life.